# What has triggered the massive number of user removals?

Tags: discussion, support

What has triggered the massive number of user removals shown in  https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/674/tim?tab=reputation?

Is it related to my account?Thanks.

Sorry for being sensitive. It happened at this moment when  [I am   not recovered from the repetitive "abuse" by some super powerful and privileged users and moderators at the infamous stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385434/being-bullied-by-some-users-and-moderators).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this has nothing at all to do with your account. How could it? It also has nothing to do with the moderation team here. We didn't remove this user, [someone from SE did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328644/203101). In fact, as a mod, I don't even have any way of knowing what user was removed or why.

But just to set your mind at ease, you are not alone:

- [Gilles lost 549 reputation points.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles?tab=reputation)
- [Stéphane Chazelas lost 280 reputation points.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas?tab=reputation)
- [slm lost 65 reputation points.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm?tab=reputation)
- [Stephen Kitt lost 240 reputation points.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt?tab=reputation)
- [Kusalananda lost 366 reputation points.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda?tab=reputation)
- [I lost 230 reputation points.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon?tab=reputation)

Comment: Thanks. It is not a single user removal. It is a large number of user removals (maybe nearly 100 users' removals around 2:30am today). They are shown in the link I gave , but I don't know why the link I gave suddently changed to show just one user removal

Comment: @Tim that link would always have shown one, and I now know it was indeed one user. It's just that the user was active on many sites, and so are you, so your "Achievements" drop-down menu showed multiple "user was removed" messages. But I believe that was the same user on multiple sites.

Comment: Not really, I just found that the link I gave shows many users' removals on the mobile site, but just one user's removal on the desktop site.

Comment: @Tim ah, yes, you're quite right. That seems to show one "user removed" for each post of yours that was affected. It's still most likely just one user though.